# Julia: inject code containing keyword into scipt

Tags: macros, julia, keyword

I have a function containing a for loop. I would like to add an argument to that function that lets me chose to run the loop parrallel using
`Threads.@threads for i in ...`.
I thus just need to inject `Threads.@threads` in front of the loop. Macros don´t work as they can´t handle keywords.
Alterntively I could have something like

```
if parrallel
    inject("Threads.@threads for i in 1:n")
else
    inject("for i in 1:n")
end

    loop content....
end
```

I can´t find any way to insert code like that. What to do?

It would of course be an option to put the whole loop in a function and just use an if else containing the for loops over the function but I would prefer the rest of the code as is.

Comment: Injecting code just in time doesn't sound like a nice or easy way to proceed. There is a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32871620/julia-inject-code-into-function .

Comment: I read that but I thought the raised concerns don't apply because I want to do it within a function not from the outside of the function.

Comment: What is the reason that you want to inject code like this? This seems to me like a really odd way to program stuff. It cannot be compiled correctly, it is difficult to do and doesn't have any apparent advantage. Am I wrong?

Comment: incompentence maybe ;)
I did think that it might not be optimal, but basically i was just looking for a way to leave as much of the code as is as possible.

Answer (score 2):

> It would of course be an option to put the whole loop in a function and just use an if else containing the for loops over the function but I would prefer the rest of the code as is.

Note that higher order functions and syntactic sugar like [`do` blocks](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/functions/#Do-Block-Syntax-for-Function-Arguments) make such solutions relatively straightforward to develop and easy to read:

You can start defining two higher-order functions that abstract away the for loop.

```
# This one is basically `Base.foreach`
function sequential_for(f, iterable)
    for i in iterable
        f(i)
    end
end

# A thread-parallel version
function parallel_for(f, iterable)
    Threads.@threads for i in iterable
        f(i)
    end
end
```

Then your function can dynamically decide which version of the for loop it wants to use:

```
function my_fun(n; parallel=false)
    for_loop = parallel ? parallel_for : sequential_for
    
    x = zeros(Int, n)

    # The do syntax avoids having to either
    # - define the loop body as a named function elsewhere, or
    # - put an hard-to-read lambda directly as argument to `for_loop`
    for_loop(1:n) do i
        x[i] = Threads.threadid()
        sleep(0.1)  # Let's make sure we see the effect of parallelism :-)
    end
    return x
end
```

Example use:

```
julia> @time my_fun(10)
  1.025307 seconds (299 allocations: 17.109 KiB)
10-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1
 1
 1
 1
 1
 1
 1
 1
 1
 1

julia> @time my_fun(10, parallel=true)
  0.235430 seconds (18.44 k allocations: 979.714 KiB)
10-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1
 1
 2
 2
 3
 4
 5
 6
 7
 8
```

Answer (score 1):

Inserting code just in time doesn't work nicely or easily. The compiler would not know what to do and it would not be optimized at all and would not be safe. For a similar question see: [Julia: inject code into function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32871620/julia-inject-code-into-function) .

I would write the code either by writing a separate function for the for loop (in my opinion the cleaner way), or by leaving the for loop inside your first function and just writing it double.

Something like:

```
function forloopcontent()
    println(Threads.threadid())
end

function f(parallel::Bool)
    if parallel
        Threads.@threads for i in 1:10
            forloopcontent()
        end
    else for i in 1:10
            forloopcontent()
        end
    end
end
```

Otherwise, you could also write another function for the parallel version and two different methods for the normal one. I.e.:

```
function f(;parallel::Bool=false)
    parallel ? (return par_f()) : (return f())
end 

function f()
    for i in 1:10
        println(Threads.threadid())
    end
end

function par_f()
    Threads.@threads for i in 1:10
        println(Threads.threadid())
    end
end
```

This version can be called as `f(;parallel=true)` for the parallel version or `f(;parallel=false)` for the not parallel version.